# How to Scroll multiple UL set in verticaly?

Tags: html, css, css-float, html-lists

I want to scroll multiple `ul` set in vertically.

```
<section class="main_nav_dropdown dark_blue fl">
    <ul class="unstyled fl archive_list"></ul>
    <ul class="unstyled fl archive_list"></ul>
    <ul class="unstyled fl archive_list"></ul>
    <ul class="unstyled fl archive_list"></ul>
    <ul class="unstyled fl archive_list"></ul>
    <ul class="unstyled fl archive_list"></ul>
    <ul class="unstyled fl archive_list"></ul>
    <ul class="unstyled fl archive_list"></ul>
   </section>
```

each `ul` is `float: left` and have fixed `width` in `200px`. outer `section` is `900px width` and `overflow-x: scroll;`. How can I show all ul's virtically with a scroll. Because now after 3rd `ul` others came to bottom as the image.[image]

Comment: tabular data should be presented in a `table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must specify one more element between section and ULs or change `<section>` to `<iframe>` to grasp the ULs..

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <ul class="foo left"><li>&nbsp;</li></ul>
        <ul class="foo left"><li>&nbsp;</li></ul>    
        <ul class="foo left"><li>&nbsp;</li></ul>
        <ul class="foo left"><li>&nbsp;</li></ul>
    </div>
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CTvHa/

Excuse my self for my english...